# Position of 20096 in triangular array of all natural numbers

Tags: matrices, natural-numbers

Write the set of all natural numbers in a triangular array as

[image: Infinite Triangular Array]

Find the row number and column number where $20096$ occurs. For example, $8$ occurs on row: $3$, column: $2$

Now, the upper row is obviously of the form $\large f(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Running a computer program I get that at $n=200$, $f(n)$ has the value $20100$.

I used the program to determine the value closest to $20096$. So now I know $20100$ occurs at row:$1$, column: $200$, thus $20096$ can be reached by going bottom-left for five steps? Am I counting right? Should it be row:$5$ , column:$195$?

Also can anyone figure out a less "hacky" way to solve this? Because this solution was completely dependent on finding $f(200) = 20100$ which was completely trial and error, albeit made easier by the fact that I didn't have to do it by hand. Also *why* exactly are the numbers in the top row of the form of the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, I can't see a clear connection?

Comment: Your counting is off; you increased row number by $4$, but decreased column number by $5$. It ought to be row $5$, column $196$. Also, why the first row looks like it does is explained by looking at the length of each diagonal on which you place numbers (thinking along the lines of an induction proof won't hurt). Hve you ever heard the term "triangular number"?

Comment: Ah, yes I see. Right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let x be the number of the column and y be the number of the row where your number exists. Let z be your number.

As you noticed, you have to find the number n where $f(n-1)\lt z\le f(n)$. Then, n+1 will be the number of the diagonal: $x+y=n+1$.

Then you will have to find out your row: $x=f(n)-z+1$

So **for your example**: $19900=f(199)\lt 20096\le f(200)=20100$

and $x=f(200)-20096+1=5$.

So $y=n-x+1$. $y=200-5+1=196$

The position is $(x,y)=(5,196)$

Comment: that was great thanks.

Comment: To find the diagonal, you can note that $f(n)=\frac 12n(n+1)$, so $n^2+n-2f(n)=0, n=-\frac 12+\sqrt{1+8f(n)}$, rounding up to the next whole number.  That way you don't have to count through the $n$'s

Comment: Ah, yes that's good @RossMillikan